# Get correct logic for self invoking method

Tags: java, arraylist

I was writing a method that should get formatted output of an ArrayList valueList that contains some values. This method should write found values to a class private ArrayList "`formatedList`".

Method should compare initial value rootId againgst objectsClean and see if it finds same value. If found it reads lines till "END" is reached. Found values are writen to tempArray and method is self invoked with tempArray that contains some found values.

Also every String that found in ArrayList is removed(Just to be sure that method doesnt find save value twice). Also there could be that bbbb,cccc,dddd or eeee come more then once till "END" is reached and they are younique so thause should be saved and passed to the method to look for them.

Is there any better ways to loop trough ArrayList and fine needen information. (Not all values are at the same position. Some are at the top some are at the button and there is need to loop arrayList everyTime to fine currect value im looking for.)

P.s have updated my output

What am I doing wrong? I just cant get it. Trying to solve this line for two days now.

> Method that causes problem. The output is not right.

```
private void getValues(ArrayList<String> rootId, ArrayList<String> objectsClean) {
    ArrayList<String> tempRoot = new ArrayList<>(objectsClean);
    ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
    listToDestroy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(objectsClean);
    for (String s : rootId) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    for (String s : rootId) {
        int count = 0;
        tempArray.clear();
        for (String a : listToDestroy) {
            count++;
            if (a.equals(s)) {
                while (true) {
                    count++;
                    if (tempRoot.get(count).equals("END")) {
                        break;
                    } else if (tempRoot.get(count).contains("aaaa")) {
                        tempArray.add(tempRoot.get(count));
                        objectsClean.remove(count);
                    } else if (tempRoot.get(count).contains("bbbb")) {
                        tempArray.add(tempRoot.get(count));
                        objectsClean.remove(count);
                    } else if (tempRoot.get(count).contains("cccc")) {
                        tempArray.add(tempRoot.get(count));
                        objectsClean.remove(count);
                    } else if (tempRoot.get(count).contains("dddd")) {
                        tempArray.add(tempRoot.get(count));
                        objectsClean.remove(count);
                    } else if (tempRoot.get(count).contains("eeee")) {
                        tempArray.add(tempRoot.get(count));
                        objectsClean.remove(count);
                    }

                }
                if (!tempArray.isEmpty()) {
                    getValues(tempArray, objectsClean);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> objectsClean looks something like that

```
aaaa
Text
bbbb
yyyy
END
bbbb
Text
cccc
yyyy
END
cccc
Text
dddd
yyyy
END
dddd
Text
eeee
yyyy
END
1aaaa
1Text
1bbbb
1yyyy
END
1bbbb
1Text
1cccc
1yyyy
END
1cccc
1Text
1dddd
1yyyy
END
1dddd
1Text
1eeee
1yyyy
END
```

> Output should look like:

```
aaaa
1aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
1bbbb
1cccc
1dddd
1eeee
```

> My output

```
aaaa
1aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
bbbb
```

Comment: please post the output you are receiving.  Will be much easier to diagnose the problem

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 nested loops. It makes code nearly unreadable. Also maybe you post all your code, it will be easier to find the problem.

Comment: Hallo, i have updated my code. This piece of code that is cousing this anomaly. Is there any better ways to Loop trough ArrayList and find neede information ? I didnt came up with better idea then self invoking method ;/

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure out what are you trying to achieve. Do you have original task description? (I mean maybe you found it as exercise in some book)

Comment: Have you try to debug your code? From what you say it seams to me that the program exit the for cycle too early.  (you never get ro 1aaaa)

Comment: #Yurii at the rootId i for initial value i will be looking for in the objectsClean. As it starts (String s : rootId) <--- this goes trough all roodId and compared each of them with objectsClean that is represented as listToDestroy that is CopyOnWriteArrayList. at the same time counter is incremented and it checks wether String a is equals string s(that would be one of the rootId's). After the condition turns true it starts from that index where condition turned true and loops until i found all values containing "aaaa"..and so on and puts then in tempArray that after it encounters "END" String.

Comment: #Jkike yes ive been trying it for two days now :D can u try to debug code ? I would like to yeah other opinion

Comment: So basically you want to remove from objectsClean list strings that are present in rootId?

Comment: Nope. My goal is to find all values that  match else if(). By looping trough given ArrayList. And actually have it ordered. Removing from objectsClean is done because i dont want to duplicate find save values.

Comment: Well, if your purpose is just basic filtering, then you should never write such a complex stuff. Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/yuriiandrieiev/b1843e2a506baddaac93 Does it perform what you want?

Comment: # Yurii, yeah its something like that, but i have a list that is 50k lines big. And i need to start filtering List from roodId that are given. And there only two posible values that are identical would look like this:
1/133-FI_SVOaaaaValue
Text
1/123-FI_SVObbbbValue
1/55-FI_SVOccccValue
END
...
1/123-FI_SVObbbbValue
Text
1/93-FI_SVOddddElem
END
...
and so on the aaaa would be initial value to search for and rest should be found on the way. Whats why i thought that loop would be good idea. Is it any help understanding issue ?

Comment: Do you mean that your matcher list ("aaaa", "bbbb", ...) is bigger than input? If not, then my algorithm should do the work anyway - it automatically resolves duplicates in output, because it outputs a set (all values are unique)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works kind of. Any advide how i get controled output. Cuz it outputing things randomly and not in order i would like to. It could be that u made my day but i dont realize it yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code style recommendation: Your main mistake in your code was an attempt to do everything you needed just in one method, in one big loop with inner loops. But in order to write simpler (means clearer and less error-prone) code, you should do one thing at a time. First, deduplicate. Second - filter out. And so on. Thing after thing, not at the same time. And that way you could easily check intermediate results or even write unit tests.

Ok, here it in sorted order:

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class MegaSolution {

    private static final List<String> matchers = asList("aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> input = Arrays.asList("aaaa", "fadsfasfd", "bbbb", "bbbb100500", "ccccfasdfs", "cccc12", "100400");
        for (String filtered : filter(input)) {
            System.out.println(filtered);
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> filter(Collection<String> input){
        final Set<String> filtered = new TreeSet<>();
        //use linkedHashSet if you want preserve input order and don't want to sort from scratch
        //final Set<String> filtered = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (String inputString : input) {
            if (matches(inputString)){
                filtered.add(inputString);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    public static boolean matches(String source){
        for (String matcher : matchers) {
            if (source != null && source.contains(matcher)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Or if you fancy Java 8:

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class MegaSolution {

    private static final List<String> matchers = asList("aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> input = Arrays.asList("aaaa", "fadsfasfd", "bbbb", "bbbb100500", "ccccfasdfs", "cccc12", "100400");
        input.stream()
                .filter(MegaSolution::matches)
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static boolean matches(String source) {
        for (String matcher : matchers) {
            if (source != null && source.contains(matcher)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u that helped me a lot. Also i realized that i do not know alot about java :D still gotta work on that one :)

Comment: You are welcome =)
But actually it not really about java, but mostly about overall style of programming. Your main mistake in your code was an attempt to do everything you needed just in one method, in one big loop with inner loops. But in order to write simpler (means cleared and less error-prone) code, you should do one thing at a time. First, deduplicate. Second - filter out. And so on. Thing after thing, not at the same time. And in that way you could easily check intermediate results or even write unit tests.